# Rails shows "0.0" instead of the real number with Money datatype (postgresql)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, orm

I am using Ruby on Rails to build a quick API and everything were fine, but when I tried to display money format in a specific table:

I can get the data (money format) from a table called "**Products**".
I cannot get the data (money format too) from a table called "**Orders**".

The diference is that **Products** has a field called *unit_price* and it is filled out by the user, but **Orders** has *subtotal*, *fee*, and *total*, which are calculated by triggers (triggers actually update the table, there are not temporaly tables where I see the data).

In the API I can see the following:

Order example:

```
{
    id_order: 14,
    id_client: 16,
    priority: 1,
    cancelled: false,
    subtotal: "0.0",
    fee: "0.0",
    total: "0.0",
    payment_type: "Crédito",
    created_at: "2018-03-23T10:53:30.704Z",
}
```

Product example:

```
{
    id_product: 301,
    dimensions: "814x630",
    description: "Ducimus et consequuntur aut similique tempore.",
    name: "Camisa sky blue L",
    weight: "63.89",
    image: "http://kihn.biz/dewitt_muller/voluptates.sint/explicabo.enim.jpg",
    unit_price: "254.64",
    stock: 102,
    stock_min: 27,
    stock_max: 165,
}
```

> NOTE: In the database manager I can see the real prices, but not in the API.

Comment: What do the `subtotal` values look like inside the database? What do they look like in the Rails console?

Comment: How did you define the columns in your database? How does your `schema.rb` for that tables look like? Do you use additional gems to support money datatypes? How does your code to read and to serialize the records look like?

Comment: Can you add both models?

Comment: @muistooshort, in console it shows like in the API, **Product**.unit_price = _0.25464e3_ and in the **Orders** table _0.0_

Comment: @spickermann I defined the colums as `money`, I not found the `schema.rb` sorry, didn't use additional gems and the code to serialize records is `render json: Order.all` and `render json: Product.all`

Comment: @Pablo , models are empty I just generate them to handle data using ORM, nothing else so far

Comment: If you look at the `orders` table using `psql`, you see `0.0` for all three `money` columns? Or if you look at the instance of the `Order` model in the Rails console you see `0.0` for all three `money` columns? Are the `Order` instances loaded before or after the trigger runs? What happens if you `Order.find(id)` for an older `id`? What happens if you call `reload` on one of the `Order`s?

Comment: Triggers are executted when I add a row in another table (not when SELECT), the 0.0 value is only shown via Ruby, and when Order.find is used, the same value is shown.

Comment: But have you looked at the data in the database without any Rails involved anywhere? There are several moving parts here (two tables, a trigger, and some Rails models), first we need to see which one isn't working as expected.